# Change input language task bar button lost on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, taskbar, input-languages

I was trying to create a script to switch between input languages using the command `Set-WinUserLanguageList`, as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1558431/change-current-keyboard-layout-via-a-bat-file).

That command worked for chaning the input, but know the switch input button that was in the task bar has disappeared, and the hotkey (Windows key + space) has stopped working.

I have checked that I still have the three languages I had before (Spanish, English and Japanese) installed, and I have checked that this button is visible according to `Settings > Taskbar > Turn system icons on and off`.

I think that the command above may have modified some system variable, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by uninstalling Spanish and Japanese and re-installing them.